# Aleatorizar List<File> destination_list

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo una consulta sobre este metodo , este metodo lo que hace es quedarse con el primer directorio que tenga un número menor de ficheros que el maximo. Mi consulta es quiero aleatorizar la variable destination_list cada vez que entra en este metodo y quisiera saber como pudiese implementarlo y probarlo.

Muchas gracias.

```
protected File getBestDirectory(List<File> destination_list) {
        
        File directory, bestDirectory = null;  
        
        int total_files, bestDirectory_files = -1;
      
        Iterator<File> iterator = destination_list.iterator();
        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            
            directory = iterator.next();
            
            String[] files = directory.list();
            
            if (files != null) {  
                
                total_files = directory.list().length;  
                
                log_.logDebug("BalancingDirSelector.getBestDirectory() " + total_files + " files found in directory " +   directory.getAbsolutePath());
                       
                if (total_files == 0) {
                    
                    bestDirectory_files = total_files;
                    bestDirectory = directory;
                    break;
                }
                if (bestDirectory_files == -1 || bestDirectory_files > total_files) {
                    bestDirectory_files = total_files;
                    bestDirectory = directory;
                }
            } else {
                log_.logWarning("BalancingDirSelector.getBestDirectory() Could not list directory " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
                        
            }
        }
        if (bestDirectory_files == -1) {
            bestDirectory = destination_list.get(0);
               log_.logError("BalancingDirSelector.getBestDirectory() Could not list destination directories. Setting destination to " +  bestDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                                           
        }
        return bestDirectory;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por *aleatorizar* te refieres a que quieres mezclar los elementos de la lista?

Comment: Si eso es quiero que aletorize los elementos de la lista , no se si con la clase ramdon podre hacerlo tipo asi ..    Random aleatorio = new Random();   File archivoAleatorio = destination_list.get(aleatorio.nextInt(destination_list.size()));

Comment: Pregunta morbosa... ¿y para qué quieres cambiar el orden de los elementos si de todas formas no usas una solución óptima (no es el directorio que tenga menos ficheros de todos, sino le primero que tenga menos archivos que el primer directorio que compruebes)?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `Collections.shuffle(list)`, probarlo con test unitarios puede resultar complicado ya que justamente al ser al azar, no hay manera de saber previamente cómo quedará ordenado, e incluso una de las posibilidades es que te quede como la lista original.